# How to read JSON data, that is sent from Android, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, json, web-services

I have created a mobile application that scans the surrounding Bluetooth devices and I am able to put the devices into an array list.

Now, using the http POST method, I have to send a JSONObject having this array list to a url and even for this I have written an expected code on the android app(I am sure this code will work because I have already worked on this using POST method to URL's and displaying the response on the activity).

But, how to listen the JSONObject, sent by any android app to the URL, parse it and show it on that particular URL's webpage ?
(In short I am looking for a Javascript code which can handle this and show the list.)

Answer (score 0):

if you already have the URL where the JSON is being posted to you can do:

plain js:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'URL', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

with jquery:

```
var getData = $.getJSON('URL');

getData.done(function(data){
     // you have access to data here
});
```